# Como fazer perguntas para o usuário em Python, sem executar constantemente?

Tags: python, loop

Estou criando um código em Python que peça o *nick* de um *player* e, conforme o usuário responder, ele receberá uma resposta, confiram:

```
player = (input('Digite o nick desejado:'))

if player == 'Phil' :
  print('Player encrenqueiro,nível de habilidades:razoável.')
elif player == 'Knuckles' :
    print('Ótimo player,muito cooperativo,nível de habilidades:alta!')
elif player == 'Bubble':
    print('Considerado um dos melhores players no game,extremamente flexível e\n adaptável ao jogo de seu parceiro,nível de habilidades:altíssima!')
```

O problema é que não sei como fazer para que o programa não pare, até o usuário digitar todos os *nicks* que ele quiser. Não quero que ele fique executando novamente toda vez para obter uma resposta, quero continuamente...

Cada um receberá uma mensagem diferente, para cada *nick* digitado, e é isso que quero que seja feito, após eles digitarem um *nick* e obterem uma resposta, quero que recebam um "Digite o próximo *player*" e assim por diante...

Comment: O ideal seria você postar o código em texto ao invés de imagem. SObre a sua dúvida, você pode fazer um laço de repetição, ou repetir o trecho que lê o input uma vez para cada if no lugar do elif

Comment: Você poderia fazer uma demonstração disso?somente sei usar while e for repetidas vezes com alguma mensagem,puramente isso,não sei como usar após o usuário responder algo,e sim,na próxima postarei o código ao invés da imagem,obrigado.

Comment: EDIT: código em texto agora.

Comment: Já conseguiste resolver? Com um ciclo while fazes isso

Comment: Ainda não Miguel,preciso de uma pequena demonstração,se possível,entendo melhor olhando,procurei bastante antes de vir perguntar aqui,mas tudo que acho é como usar o while e for PURAMENTE(somente isso),e meu objetivo é repetir a pergunta após o usuário ter recebido uma resposta para o nick que ele digitou,exemplo: digite um nick: morango/resposta: morango é um ótimo player,Digite o próximo player:

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: Leonardo Alves Machado Você acha mesmo que não li sobre while/for antes de vir aqui perguntar?como eu disse,sei usá-los puramente,e não colocá-los para dar uma resposta particular,para cada nick que o usuário digitar,e após isso pedir para digitar o próximo player,e assim por diante,entende?é confuso de explicar,haha,desculpem.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta, não é pra mostrar novamente a frase caso ela ja tenha sido digitada?

Answer (score 3):

Embora a outra resposta produza o resultado esperado, não acho que seja uma boa solução, visto que, se precisar adicionar mais opções de *nicks*, você terá que adicionar outras condições na estrutura. Não é bom para manutenção da aplicação.

A solução que eu proponho é armazenar os *nicks* junto com as respectivas frases em um dicionário:

```
NICKNAMES = {
    'Phil': 'Player encrenqueiro, nível de habilidades: razoável.',
    'Knuckles': 'Ótimo player, muito cooperativo, nível de habilidades: alta!',
    'Bubble': 'Considerado um dos melhores players no game, extremamente flexível e\n adaptável ao jogo de seu parceiro, nível de habilidades: altíssima!',
    'Woss': 'Pica das galáxias. Com certeza o melhor! Boa escolha, nível de habilidades: mais que 8000!'
}
```

E, já prevendo que o usuário possa digitar outra opção além dessas, definir uma mensagem a exibir por padrão:

```
DEFAULT = 'Huum, não sei o que dizer sobre esse player :('
```

Para ler a entrada do usuário, utilizar um laço infinito até que o mesmo confirme o *nick* que ele deseja utilizar.

```
while True:
    print("Qual nick gostaria de utilizar?")
    print("Que tal essas opções:", list(NICKNAMES.keys()), '?')

    nick = input("Nick: ")

    print(NICKNAMES.get(nick, DEFAULT))

    confirm = input('Gostaria de manter esse nick? [S/n] ')

    if confirm in ['S', 's', '']:
        break
    else:
        print()

print('Ok, seu nick será {}'.format(nick))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DarkmagentaForestgreenFlashmemory)</sup>

Assim, se precisar definir outros *nicks*, basta adicionar no dicionário, que poderia ser uma estrutura armazenada em um banco de dados ou até em arquivo JSON, por exemplo.

Uma saída possível deste código seria:

```
Qual nick gostaria de utilizar?
Que tal essas opções: ['Phil', 'Knuckles', 'Bubble', 'Woss'] ?
Nick:  Phil
Player encrenqueiro, nível de habilidades: razoável.
Gostaria de manter esse nick? [S/n]  n

Qual nick gostaria de utilizar?
Que tal essas opções: ['Phil', 'Knuckles', 'Bubble', 'Woss'] ?
Nick:  Knuckles
Ótimo player, muito cooperativo, nível de habilidades: alta!
Gostaria de manter esse nick? [S/n]  n

Qual nick gostaria de utilizar?
Que tal essas opções: ['Phil', 'Knuckles', 'Bubble', 'Woss'] ?
Nick:  Bubble
Considerado um dos melhores players no game, extremamente flexível e
 adaptável ao jogo de seu parceiro, nível de habilidades: altíssima!
Gostaria de manter esse nick? [S/n]  n

Qual nick gostaria de utilizar?
Que tal essas opções: ['Phil', 'Knuckles', 'Bubble', 'Woss'] ?
Nick:  Horacio
Huum, não sei o que dizer sobre esse player :(
Gostaria de manter esse nick? [S/n]  n

Qual nick gostaria de utilizar?
Que tal essas opções: ['Phil', 'Knuckles', 'Bubble', 'Woss'] ?
Nick:  Woss
Pica das galáxias. Com certeza o melhor! Boa escolha, nível de habilidades: mais que 8000!
Gostaria de manter esse nick? [S/n]  s
Ok, seu nick será Woss
```

Comment: Muito boa a dica,principalmente sobre o dicionário(destaque para o player "Woss" hein!) salvei sua resposta aqui nos documentos amigo,muito útil ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assim? Se for eu comento o código depois.

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/FumblingNaturalModes

```
nicks_consultados = []

while len(nicks_consultados) < 3:
  print("Quantidade {}".format(len(nicks_consultados)))

  player = (input('Digite o nick desejado:'))

  if player == 'Phil':
    print('Player encrenqueiro,nível de habilidades:razoável.')

    if 'Phil' not in nicks_consultados:
      nicks_consultados.append('Phil')

  elif player == 'Knuckles' :
    print('Ótimo player,muito cooperativo,nível de habilidades:alta!')

    if 'Knuckles' not in nicks_consultados:
      nicks_consultados.append('Knuckles')
  elif player == 'Bubble':
    print('Considerado um dos melhores players no game,extremamente flexível e\n adaptável ao jogo de seu parceiro,nível de habilidades:altíssima!')

    if 'Bubble' not in nicks_consultados:
      nicks_consultados.append('Bubble')

print("Terminou")
```

**Explicação**

Eu criei um vetor `nicks_consultados`, onde eu vou salvar quais nicks já foram digitados.

`while len(nicks_consultados) < 3:`

Nesse trecho eu pego a quantidade de itens da lista enquanto for menor que 3 (o usuário não digitou todos os nicks pelo menos uma vez eu repito o processo.

Dentro dos ifs eu verifico se o nick não está na lista caso ele não estiver eu adiciono.

Comment: Exatamente Laerte,perfeito,obrigado,agora tentarei entender o código,valeu!

Comment: Veja se deu pra entender.

Comment: Sim,entendi perfeitamente agora,obrigado.

Comment: Booa, python é muito legal, bons estudos. :)